# Какие есть программы для организации рабочего стола в Windows 10?

Tags: windows, поиск-программ

Подскажите, какие есть программы для организации рабочего стола в windows 10?
(Аналоги Stardock Fences)

ObjectDock

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как в ObjectDock поменять шрифт подписей иконой, и убрать у них тень?

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов:

[Real Decktop](https://real-desktop.ru.uptodown.com/windows) – бесплатная версия программы Real Desktop - довольно оригинального трехмерного рабочего стола, на котором все ваши элементы будут распологаться в 3D пространстве. Особого внимания заслуживает наличие "физики": иконки обладают инерцией, сталкиваются, разлетаются в разные стороны.

[Nimi places](http://mynimi.net/Projects/Nimi-Places/Download/) – это бесплатный инструмент для удобной организации рабочего стола Windows 7. Инструмент позволяет размещать ваши любимые папки, диски, сетевые папки и даже некоторые устройства на рабочем столе, не загромождая рабочий стол.

[Xlaunchpad](https://xwidget.com/xlaunchpad.html) – менеджер для работы с ярлыками на рабочем столе. Интерфейс программы похож на меню устройств работающих под Андроид, можно прокручивать слайды ярлыков движением мышки.Кроме того программа позволяет менять иконки в формате PNG, настраивать размер, группировать и прочее.

Comment: Есть ли приложение которое создает на рабочем столе виджет со вкладками TAB переключаясь между которыми можно менять содержимое пространства?

Comment: вряд ли, сейчас поищу потом скажу нашёл или нет.

Comment: Те что есть какие-то корявые все...

Comment: @Biomotor ага..

Comment: а есть что-то типа RocketDock или ObjectDock, но с возможностью раскрытия списка при нажатии на иконку?

Comment: Нашел прогу, ObjectDock, там можно делать вкладки, кто бы помог разобраться с настройками стилей и цветом црифта... ?

Comment: Да нашёл прогу типа RocketDock и ObjectDock, называется CairoDock https://ruprogi.ru/software/cairo-dock. Там можно раскрывать список при нажатии на иконку